# Call Particular Javascript function on page load

Tags: javascript, html

I have a page with 7 sections of information contained in a Javascript accordion.  The accordion sections are opened by making a function call with an index contained in it. ie: runAccordion(3);  I would like to link to this page from other areas of my site and have the appropriate accordion open when the page loads.  Linking to the page as www.domain.com/page.php#myAccordion just places the appropriate accordion at the top of the page but does not open it. Is there a way to pass a parameter to be processed on page load and then call the right function?

Answer (score 0):

Call a function onLoad or with jQuery document.ready that gets document.location.href and parses the query string parameters. See [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript/901144#901144) for an example.

The URL to your page would be www.domain.com/page.php?myAccordion=3